# Expo-cli is installed but "-bash: expo: command not found"

Tags: node.js, npm, expo

I'm new to expo-cli and keep running into this on the terminal

```
expo init myproject
-bash: expo: command not found
```

First, I tried uninstall and installing via

```
sudo npm uninstall -g expo-cli && sudo npm i -g expo-cli
+ expo-cli@2.6.14
```

Second, I checked nodejs to see what version it was running on:

```
node -v
v10.15.0
npm -v
6.4.1
```

Third, I tried to see if it was an environment issue and adding a path via:

```
sudo vim ~/.bash_profile
```

inserting the following to the end:

```
# NPM global installs
export PATH=$PATH:~/.npm-global/bin
```

Did not solve the issue.

Comment: There is no need to use `sudo` to edit your own files. It is even wrong to use `sudo` to edit any file that is not a system configuration file (and nothing inside `~` is a system configuration file). It is correct that you added the path in `.bash_profile` but it doesn't have any effect now; this file is read on the next login. You have to either run it inside the current shell (`. ~/.bash_profile`) or update the value of `PATH` in memory (run the `PATH=...` line directly on the shell prompt).

Comment: @axiac so I tried updating the path directly on the current shell and it still doesn't recognize `expo`. I also tried `npm install expo-cli` directly on to my folder and updating the path, but that also failed...

Comment: Hi @PeteKang try it by react-native-cli instead of expo-cli

Comment: @PeteKang were you able to fix this? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @AT92 I ended up using react-native-cli

Comment: Can you check this, I have already answered:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62971258/expo-cli-installed-but-when-running-any-expo-command-i-get-zsh-command-not-fou/64170054#64170054

Answer (score 2):

at firs do this:

```
npm install expo-cli
```

then it installed run this command:

```
npm install expo-cli --global
```

it worked for me , and i hope it works for you too ;)

Answer (score 0):

First off, I am not going to take credit, This issue is was solved a long time ago and it is quite easy to solve, although not permanently yet.

So it is said that it is an issue with the environment, where as the device you're using need to know where the programmes are.

-Check if `/users/me/.npm-global/bin` by running:
`echo $PATH`
-It is isn't run
`export PATH=$PATH:~/.npm-global/bin`
-After that you should be good to get back to the shell

```
source ~/.bash_profilez
```

Like I said am not taking credit for this. [Here](https://forums.expo.io/t/expo-cli-looks-installed-but-expo-command-not-found/14535/4) is where i found our life saver;