# Expo-cli installed but when running any expo command I get "zsh: command not found: expo"

Tags: react-native, expo

I have installed expo-cli globally but when I try to run any expo code like `expo start` from anywhere, I get:

`zsh: command not found: expo`

echo $PATH returns:

`/Users/amitg/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/amitg/.npm-global/bin`

I am using macOS, catalina.

Comment: Did you put sudo before the install command, ie: `sudo npm install -g expo-cli`?

Comment: Yes the second time I installed it, I did it with sudo.

Answer (score 17):

The correct command to run expo in macOS these days is `npx expo`.

e.g.

`npx expo init my_app`

**If expo-cli is not installed, it will provide you with instructions to install**

Comment: This results in an endless loop of `This command requires Expo CLI.` `Do you want to install it globally [y/n]`

Comment: you enter `y` and it will install expo, if it's not already installed. That's what stated in **bold** in my answer.

Comment: Yes I know. And like I said it kept looping. Installing and then prompting to install.

Comment: probably try removing the package globally `npm uninstall -g expo-cli`

Answer (score 8):

The answer is pretty simple.

just add **npm binaries to your path**

1. `echo $PATH`
2. `export PATH=$PATH:~/.npm-global/bin`
3. `source ~/.profile` or `source ~/.bash_profile`

That's It, It will work now, Just go check it
`expo init myproject`

Comment: After the first 2 steps, it worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: I have a mac and this also did the trick for me. Thank you for this!

Comment: This was super helpful thanks! A note for other people - run command 1, then command 2, then run command 1 again and you should see the .npm-global/bin on the end, if you do run command three and check again - it should work

Comment: first two command did the work for me, Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

FOR MACOS

So I recommend your `echo $PATH` command should be `/usr/local/bin`. Probably you have install Node on the website via .pkg you have downloaded. I have tried to remove and reinstall multiple times but it wasn't work on MacOS Catalina. I highly recommend to install via NVM. Okay I got you at first it sounds like you don't want any third party dependency to install more than Official website of NodeJS, alright I understand your concern, but I have tried for 2 hours straight and it is not worked. NVM is not really that bad, it is helpful and handy and you don't have to reinvent the wheel. I will show you very simple way, no mess up.

So I recommend you to remove and uninstall it first:

1. `brew uninstall node`
2. `which node` `//if this not found or return empty it means you have removed it`
3. `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node`
4. `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/`
5. `brew doctor`
6. `brew cleanup --prune-prefix`

Then:

1. `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node`
2. `brew uninstall --force node`

MAKE SURE YOU ARE DEACTIVATE ANY VIRTUAL ENVIRONMENT ***:

1. `brew update`
2. `brew install nvm`

Then create folder for NVM (no need to care which directory you are in now)

1. `mkdir ~/.nvm`

Now add these lines to ~/.bash_profile ( or ~/.zshrc for macOS Catalina or later) by `nano  ~/.bash_profile`: **(Marks my word, ADD belows line to bash_profile or zsh, not running those two commands below, ADD THEM!!!)**

1. `export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm`
2. `source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh`

Add the NVM Directory Paths to Your Shell Profile (When Needed)

1. `nano .zshrc`
2. `export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion`
3. Type `CTRL + x` in your Mac
4. Type `Shift + y` in your Mac
5. Hit `Enter or Return` key

Then you need to QUIT/CLOSE ALL TERMINAL entirely to make effect

To see what Node versions are available to install run:

1. `nvm ls-remote`
   You will see list of Node version available. I recommend to install any node version with Latest LTS (green color text)

For me, I just needed the latest point release of Node version 12.8.4 LTS stable released during my answer for you so I ran

1. `nvm install 12.18.4` or `nvm install --lts` 
   Otherwise a useful reference in 2022: `https://heynode.com/tutorial/install-nodejs-locally-nvm/`

Verify your node version:

1. `node --version`

THEN FINALLY INSTALL expo cli

1. `npm install --global expo-cli`

Check expo installation:

1. `expo --version`

I am a student I tried many ways and this work for me and I hope I would be part to help you. Comment if sth still go unplanned.

Comment: You are not a student in this case :). Thank you for your comprehensive instructions which helped me pretty much!

Comment: You're welcome. I just tried to make an answer that won't waste people's time.

Comment: It was the only solution that worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

**I am getting the same loop.**  This is how you fix your expo-cli.

1. **npx uninstall -g expo-cli**
2. **npx update (in your project directory).**

**Works like a charm.** No endless loop. No editing the bash or zsh files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue: the following command worked for me on mac :

1. sudo npm install -g expo-cli
2. sudo npx create-expo-app

[image: Macbook run]

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when switched from bash to zsh, I solved it by checking at my .bash_profile (wich is located at ~/.bash_profile) and I found this export:

```
 export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

given that in bash everything worked correctly I decided to copy the export and replace default export in .zshrc file (wich is located at ~./zshrc)

Your ~/.zshrc file should look something like this:

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
#export PATH=/usr/local/bin/npm:$PATH
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"
```

Then restart your terminal by pressing cmd + Q and you're done, hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

If none of the above work for you try:

`sudo npm install --unsafe-perm -g expo-cli`

hopefully this helps.

Answer (score -1):

use "sudo yarn global add expo-cli" instead of "yarn global add expo-cli"

Answer (score -1):

When i got a new macbook i faced the same challange.
Here's how i fixed the issue:

alias expo="`npm config get prefix`/bin/expo"

Now try expo start again, it should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).