# "zsh: command not found: expo" on macOS

Tags: macos, npm, expo

I am trying to start a React Native project but when I type `expo init some-project` I get  `zsh: command not found: expo` despite having expo installed.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62971258/expo-cli-installed-but-when-running-any-expo-command-i-get-zsh-command-not-fou

Comment: Thank you, I've seen this and the echo path that I get is different (for some reason includes Python??). Maybe this is why the solutions aren't working for me..